# PHP PDO Update SQL Syntax Error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am new to `PDO` and I'm trying to build my own CRUDS application. I already created `CRD` but I'm getting stuck with Updating user information. It seems that I have a problem with my syntax, but I thoroughly checked the documentation and I can't figure out what is wrong with the code. It's passing me this error:

`ERROR: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Doe, email=johndoe@gmail.com, location=New York City WHERE id=1' at line 1`

Here is my code:

```
include('database.inc.php');

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$id = $_POST['userId']; // 1
$name = $_POST['employee_name']; // John Doe
$email = $_POST['email']; // johndoe@gmail.com
$location = $_POST['location']; // New York City

    try {

     $query = "UPDATE users SET employee_name=$name, email=$email, location=$location WHERE id=$id";
     $statement = $conn->prepare($query);
     $statement->execute();

     header('Location: ../index.php');

     } catch(PDOException $e) {

    echo 'ERROR: ' .$e->getMessage();

     }

}
```

Comment: Put single quotes around your variables.. -_- `$query = "UPDATE users SET employee_name='$name', email='$email', location='$location' WHERE id=$id";` and .. **Note:** `This (`mysql_*`) extension is deprecated as of `PHP 5.5.0`, and will be removed in the future. Instead, **Prepared Statements** of [`MySQLi`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [`PDO_MySQL`](http://in2.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) extension should be used to ward off SQL Injection attacks !`

Comment: May I ask, which documentation you were checking?

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran may be you think you comment over a bit?

Comment: @YourCommonSense, _How does that annoy you_ ?

Comment: Okay it's working now. Thank's for the help!

Comment: OP: That's not how you prepare queries - you are still vulnerable to SQLi

Comment: @YourCommonSense, I really would if that comment came from a highly experienced person.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran let me please inform you that even edited version doesn't make too much sense as well, as the OP aren't using mysql ext.

Comment: @YourCommonSense, This is one of your most valuable comments (ofcourse a correct one) after all these years. I agree. +1 to your comment.

Comment: I'm still studying and I'm new to programming that's why I had to ask. After I finish this simple CRUDS application, I will study cleaning up the code and making it more secured. Please don't be too harsh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you didn't put quotes around the string values in the SQL. But you should use parametrized queries, not substitute variables into the SQL. This solves the quoting problem, and also prevents SQL injection.

```
$query = "UPDATE users SET employee_name=:name, email=:email, location=:location WHERE id=:id";
$statement = $conn->prepare($query);
$statement->execute(array(':name' => $name, 
                          ':email' => $email,
                          ':location' => $location,
                          ':id' => $id));
```

Comment: Okay Sir thank you very much for this tip. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Try surrounding the variables in the statement with single quotes ( ' )

```
$query = "UPDATE users SET employee_name='$name', email='$email',
location='$location' WHERE id='$id'";
```

Comment: Yep, surrounding the variables with single quotes worked for me. Thanks for the help.

Comment: The bad answer become 1000 times worse then it suits the OP. It's a shame to do a disservice instead of answer